# Selecting a particular row in mysql from visual studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT phone_number from contacts_table where name='textBox1.Text'", con);
```

If i use this code, it doesn't work, but when I use a specific name from the table, for example Joey, it shows me the number. Do you have any idea what the problem might be? It shows the row where the number should be, but it is empty.

Comment: you actruall are looking for the text textbox1.text in your column name, switch to prepared statements with parameters , which is also more secure

Comment: It cannot work - You query for contact with `name='textBox1.Text'`, not with the name which is stored in `textBox1.Text` property. You must insert this value into the query text via parameter (or directly) then execute. MySQL cannot know that somewhere on some client there exists some textbox with some value...

Comment: I think you are looking for something more like `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT phone_number from contacts_table where name='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);`